# Why is the recursion in the namehash algorithm?

Tags: solidity, ens, eip, namehash

The algorithm is described in [eip-137](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-137.md#namehash-algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

The recursion this EIP refers to is the following line:

`return sha3(namehash(remainder) + sha3(label))`

I am not sure of all of the reasons for this, but I do know that hashing the values (specifically the user generated `remainder` and `label` in some cases) allows for visual verification that the `remainder` and `label` are truly the expected values.

ENS had an issue early on with [zero-width spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) that allowed people to register what *seemed* like ethereum.eth, but in reality was eth​er​eum.eth with one or more whitespaces in them. Visual inspection would have told you that these were the same values, but hashing the two values produce a different result.

There may be additional reasons for the recursive hashing, but this is one that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help @shane!

The zero-width spaces are a problem handled by the [normalization](https://docs.ens.domains/contract-api-reference/name-processing#normalising-names) and the [UI](https://docs.ens.domains/contract-api-reference/name-processing#handling-of-ambiguous-names).

I have found more use cases in the ENS [doc](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/ens/latest/ens.pdf) and from what I understand now is that the recursive call in namehash enables some nice lookup functionality similar to existing DNS as well as fixed length keys in the registry store.

As everything is hashed I can register a subdomain by sending `namehash('bar.eth'), web3.sha3('foo')` without exposing `foo` in clear text on chain. Very nice design.

Comment: recursive hashing also allows ownership creation and transfer for subdomains via function setSubnodeOwner(bytes32 node, bytes32 label, address owner) just like for the DNS: you are owner of bar.eth and register lib1.bar.eth